# Programmatically change constraints in cell layout to be centered - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout that is using ConstraintLayout inside a cell. When the condition is met, I set the visibility to gone for 2 of the 3 views. Afterwards, I attempt to reset the constraints for the views, so that the only visible view can be centred. However, the view is being centred horizontally instead in the center of the view. Below you can find my layout and my code for resetting the constraints.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_one"
            android:textColor="@color/white_100"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_one"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

```
private fun centerText(holder: ViewHolder) {
        holder.image = View.GONE
        holder.text_two = View.GONE
        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clear(holder.image.id)
        set.clear(holder.text_one.id)
        set.clear(holder.text_two.id)
        set.applyTo(holder.constraintLayout)
        set.constrainHeight(holder.text_one.id,
                ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
        set.constrainWidth(holder.text_one.id,
                ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
        set.connect(holder.text_one.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0)
        set.connect(holder.text_one.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0)
        set.connect(holder.text_one.id, ConstraintSet.TOP,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
        set.connect(holder.text_one.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)
        set.applyTo(holder.constraintLayout) 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: try once by setting the height of text-one to 0 instead of wrap_content, as you are matching top and bottom constraint.

Comment: Add `android:gravity="center"` to `TextView`

Comment: i cant use android:gravity="center" because if the other views are there I want them to be aligned. I only want it centered after it meets my conditions. And set 0dp results in the same output

Comment: Then use `android:textAlignment`

Comment: Im trying to modify via centerText function and not the XML. I want to leave that as is

Answer (score 0):

change visibility of image and text_two from gone to invisible. Because your parent layout height is `wrap_content`.